# Problem with installing Ubuntu over Win8

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu on disk/partition where I had Win8.
First image is partition with Win8.
I deleted all partition except last two with data (sda5 and sda6) and created partition for Ubuntu.
I installed Ubuntu and all went fine but when I try to boot it I get  bios saying select boot device. When I choose only disk I have in machine Ubuntu boots.

I really don't know why Ubuntu didn't use sda2 to create boot partition. I know there are two options for boot (MBR or bios_grub). If I got that right. I found few instructions how to create partitions for Ubuntu but all are different. Like everybody has their own way.
I know very little about Linux and any help and advice is appreciated.

Image 1
http://i61.tinypic.com/snnlms.jpg

Image 2
http://i59.tinypic.com/w6v394.jpg

Comment: Can you clarify the problem for me? Is it that you are prompted for boot device or that you don't know why Ubuntu didn't use sda2 for boot partition?

Answer (score 0):

In your Gparted there image is a column on the far right labeled "Flags". In the row with the "/" as the mount point, there should also be "boot" in the Flags column.

You can easily fix this in Gparted by:
1) highlighting the partition you want to boot from
2) select  Partition, then drop down and select "Manage flags"
3) put a check mark next to "boot", and deselect boot_bios, then "ok"

Once you've done this, reboot and the system should now boot to the partition you've selected.